# How to use webpack to manually test react components?

Tags: node.js, testing, components, webpack

I know we should use unit tests for our [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) components. But what I also want, is some way to **manually test our components in isolation**. Because we are working on small sprints in which we must deliver some finished component before having the page that first uses that component. And I want to see that full component really working (i.e. test integration with css and sub-components).

So to start with, I would like to see that new component rendered in black page that doesn't [require](/questions/tagged/require) that component directly, but to take that component name/path from a query-string parameter. And then I plan to add to that page some generic component configuration (e.g. a textbox with json representing the props to pass to that component).

The first problem I'm facing now is about how to configure [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack), [webpack-dev-middleware](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html), or [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) to be able to load a component passed by parameter.

Anyone know how to that? Or a better way to handle this?

Comment: Although we aren't using react components, we have started to break apart our components in isolation. We intend to start testing our components. It will still take a while before we get a working solution, but once we have it I'm happy to share our approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

1. Set up an entry point that uses [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).
2. Invoke `require` within that context based on your querystring. You should have you React component now. Render that through React.

In order to generate the test controls I would include the meta within the component using [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/). The form controls could be then generated using some form generator such as [plexus-form](https://github.com/AppliedMathematicsANU/plexus-form) or [tcomb-form](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form).